# Connect a NVMe m2 ssd to a SATA m2 port

Tags: ssd, sata, nvme

I want to replace my 128gb intel SATA m2 SSD with a Samsung NVMe m2. I know the ports are different so I checked the board and I think there is room for NVMe ssd. There is only one slot for a SSD and it only has the M key, see photo below of my board and current ssd.

[image: Current board and ssd]

There is no much info through the wmic tool on windows.

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
```

- Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
- Product: 0WV6GW
- Version: A04

I believe the NVMe will be a good fit but I want to make sure before buying anything that the ssd will perform as it is promised. I also read other answers on stack exchange regarding these types of ssd and still don't have a clear answer to my question.

Thanks in advance folks!

Link to Huge thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eprIih.jpg

Comment: What slot is the Samsung device?  If it's M key then it's not compatible with your device.  Most M.2 slots (on OEM hardware) are not compatible with both SATA and NVMe in my experience.  Only end consumer (high-end) motherboards have that feature.  Unless your device specifically specifies it supports NVMe it's not supported.

Comment: @Ramhound I want to upgrade to the Samsung 970 EVO Plus which has the M key only.
My current ssd has both the B and M keys.
My board has the M slot only.


Do you think it will not work?

Comment: Does your device support NVMe?

Comment: @Ramhound I can not tell you at this point, that's what I want to know, I don't have a manual with specs and the only thing I know about the board is that it's labeled with M2-SSD mark on it and has the M key slot only. I will look for the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound See my answer below regarding my findings and please correct me if I'm making a mistake please

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://www.kingston.com/en/community/articledetail/articleid/48543

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a specifications document under the support portal of Dell. This is what I found:

1. Storage configuration

   - One M.2 PCIe solid-state drive and one 2.5-inch hard drive
2. Interface

   - SATA 6 Gbps
   - PCIe Gen3x4/NVMe (version 1.1 to version 1.3)
3. Solid-state drive

   - One M.2 2230/2280 drive (SATA or PCIe/NVMe)
4. Capacity

   - Hard drive: Up to 1 TB
   - SSD: SATA: Up to 256 GB, PCIe/NVMe: Up to 512 GB

So I'd say that the Samsung 970 EVO Plus fits and will perform on my board as expected.